# Expo React Native app can't be launched in expo go. Using MacOS monterey and Iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, macos, expo

Despite having my MacBook and iPhone on the same wifi network I can't get my React Native app built with Expo to launch within my Expo go app on my iPhone or the Simulator. Using tunnel mode or not does not make a difference.

App.js file

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Error I get using `npx expo start`

[image]

Error I get using `npx expo start --tunnel`

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your app.json and are you using Tethering network somehow?

Comment: @Arti I've edited the post to include App.js. In the meantime, I've found a workaround my app loads only when I share a hotspot from my iPhone and connect my MacBook to it

Comment: your devices must be on the same network, try clicking Enter URL Manually and entering http:// before ip:port (http://192.168.1.104:19000)